Failed to create SDL window
I have a basic SDL window application in C working fine in my host system. I need to run this application in imx6dl processor, for that I added SDL2 library dependency by using IMAGE_INSTALL += " libsdl2" in yocto and generated a bin file by cross compiling the application. Having ran the application, I am unable to create SDL window and error message generated by using SDL_GetError() is
failed to create an EGL window surface

I had set added the opengl dependency in yocto by using the below lines :
IMAGE_INSTALL += " mesa"
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " opengl egl gles2 wayland"

I am using x11 SDL_VideoDriver in my host to create SDL window, but the imx6dl processor has no x11 SDL_VideoDriver. It has wayland SDL_VideoDriver. So I created the SDL application with wayland SDL_VideoDriver, set the environment variable as wayland by using export SDL_VIDEODRIVER=wayland and tried to run in the imx6dl, but no use. Could anyone please help me on this issue ??
I tried by setting the driver as wayland in application code by using
SDL_setenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER", "wayland", 1);


#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Set the SDL video driver to Wayland before SDL_Init
    SDL_setenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER", "wayland", 1);

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        printf("SDL_Init Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    int numVideoDrivers = SDL_GetNumVideoDrivers();

    printf("Number of video drivers: %d\n", numVideoDrivers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numVideoDrivers; ++i) 
        printf("Video driver %d: %s\n", i, SDL_GetVideoDriver(i));

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello SDL2", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == NULL) {
        printf("SDL_CreateWindow Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Renderer *ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    if (ren == NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        printf("SDL_CreateRenderer Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    SDL_Delay(10000);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}



I tried with above example by setting the driver to wayland .
